# How do I trigger javascript on one page from another page that is running php to recieve webhooks?

Tags: javascript, php, function

I am trying to make a custom stream alert page to add as a browser source on my obs streams. So far I have the page working using javascript functions to trigger the changes using values sent in via the function variables.

I want to be able to revieve the donate or subscribe event from my custom donation system webhook which goes to a webhook handler page and trigger the page that OBS loads to show those events.

How do I call that function and make it display on the obs source using the webhook php page to modify that other page?

So to trigger the following code:

```html
<div class="center">
    <h1 id="title"><h1>
    <h2 id="user-amount"></h3>
    <p id="message"><p>
</div>

<style>

    .center {
        padding: 70px 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }

</style>

<script>

    async function DonateAlert(title, user, amount, message){
        // do whatever you like here
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
        document.getElementById("user-amount").innerHTML = "£" + amount + " from " + user;
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;

        await setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("user-amount").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }, 5000);

        return;

    }

    async function SubAlert(title, user, message){
        // do whatever you like here
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
        document.getElementById("user-amount").innerHTML = user;
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;

        await setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("user-amount").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }, 5000);

        return;

    }

    function sleep() {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
    };

    async function triggerTest(){
        DonateAlert("Donation", "John", 10, "Thank you for the donation!");
        await sleep();
        SubAlert("Subscription", "John", "Thank you for the subscription!");
    }

</script>
```

I tried the following in the event that recieves the webhook when someone subscribes through my donate system (this is on a seperate page that exclusively manages recieving payment webhooks):

```php
echo("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jconet.co.uk/alerts'>SubAlert('SUBSCRIPTION', '".$discordName."', 'Subscribed to the ".$name." plan!')</script>");
```

Comment: Web sockets would probably be your best option. I don't have an example in front of me right now though

Comment: The usual meaning of "webhook" is, that their servers make a request to yours. In which case, the user's browser is not involved with that to begin with. So unless you are talking about something different here, when you say "webhook", your approach does not make sense to begin with. Your server needs to store the received information somewhere - in the database; session won't work, because again, user's browser not involved, so you won't know their session ID in your webhook script.

Comment: And then you need to communicate the information to the browser - via the already mentioned web sockets, or by some other form of push or pull request.